# Cannot create instance of viewmodel in xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, mvvm, viewmodel

I've been searching for an answer to this but I can't seem to find one even though the question has been asked before. I have a viewmodel and I would like to add it to the application's resources in the xaml, but when I try it says "Cannot create an instance of 'AppViewModel'.

```
<Application.Resources>
   <src:AppViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

I can add it to the resources in the code behind like this:

```
    CurrentViewModel = New AppViewModel
    Me.Resources.Add("MainViewModel", CurrentViewModel)
```

But that leaves me with squiggly lines in the xaml saying 'The resource "MainViewModel" cannot be resolved.'

Everything compiles fine and works without any issues - the bindings get bound and all that, but I would just like to get rid of the squiggly lines. I've read that you have to have a zero argument constructor on the viewmodel, but I have that and still have this error.

Comment: Maybe, there are some errors while initializing `AppViewModel` class.

Comment: Yes, I just figured out that there was an error. There was a null reference exception happening. I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out that there was a null reference happening when the view model was being initialized that wasn't happening when I initialized the view model in the code behind. Apparently the view model gets initialized at different times depending on how you add it to the resources. This seems odd to me, but it is fixed...

Comment: I'm having the same issue now, can you explain how to fix it. Is there some code needed in MainViewModel.cs? I don't really get what your saying. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jamdownian     The only thing that I can suggest is that there is something in your view model that is causing an error preventing it from being initialized. I would comment out everything and then put one thing back at at time until I figured it out.

Comment: Barry Franklin, you are right... i figured it out a while back and just saw this in my inbox. There was a control that was causing the issue..